# Why does amount of files in commits log jumps up and down?

Tags: git

I am working on a simple script which shows a count of files in each commit in the project.

Here is a command that I use to get raw data:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r <commit_hash>
```

And here is a part of output the script generates from the data:

```
id; timestamp; hash;                                    all; js; ts;
170;1490098977;c3e8d84ac06385ba6d1a9fac72d2d0293af47c2c;2659;460;1005;
171;1490098263;19b8c4539ac7501e48beee3e2f5364aeb1ee0b50;2659;460;1005;
172;1490098223;a5a44b560c498127a6adf0bd14aa88f4a47dded6;2659;460;1005;
173;1490097004;184f0c3e51d39f84f28588aaafb02418df0febb7;2730;763;761;
174;1490096803;cb7210b8d90bf4e2369b9462583addcbf59b7184;2730;763;761;
175;1490093177;4a0aa85f79fcfdf2630b5defd4a26304f83b895b;2658;460;1005;
176;1490093209;7d749f6b6f6b868e3bfbdce03cf4290309617144;2658;460;1005;
177;1490093197;83d02db47c118088378ab5bb20d828415b301f15;2658;460;1005;
178;1490092875;8afd49ecb48f430a1a6365a6107d65863493ef13;2658;460;1005;
179;1490090222;8606c74e1ef96d58a6c7d6dc904386e802f96b04;2730;763;761;
```

I use this data to create a chart.

What looks strange to me is the count of files, which sometimes is significantly different in some commits among others.

So, in commits 178-175 amount of files ("all" column) is 2658, then it jumps up to 2730, then goes down to 2659. As well as js and ts columns numbers change accordingly.

It doesn't look like it's something developers actually did to the project - add about 70 files in one commit, then remove them in the next one.

Can it be related to git logic? How this behavior can be explained?
Of about 40000 commits this situation happens quite often which makes me think it's something about how git works, though I don't understand why it happens.

**Update**

Here is the logic I use to get the output like above:

**Get all commits hashes as a list of strings:**

```
git log --pretty=format:%H
```

Which output I then split into strings and put in an array

```
[
    'c3e8d84ac06385ba6d1a9fac72d2d0293af47c2c',
    '19b8c4539ac7501e48beee3e2f5364aeb1ee0b50',
    ...
]
```

**Get files for each commit:**
I get the array and go through it then run the command below for each

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r <commitHash>
```

Which returns me a list of all files in the repo for that moment commit was created:

```
file1.js
file2.js
folder1/file3.js
folder2/file4.png
...
```

**Get amount of files for each commit:**

Now I split this output by newlines and put into a new array, and the length of it is the total amount of files I need.

Additionally, I process this output by a function which looks for some specific endings of a string, like ".js" and get an array of these files as strings and by getting its length I know the count of files with a specific file extension.

Comment: Since `git ls-tree -r` does not produce that output, there is no way for us to reproduce your problem. I suspect a bug in your script, but without access to the script, I cannot diagnose it.

Comment: Are these commits on the same branch or in parallel workflows? I ask because if one commit has the files, the next one doesn't, the next does again, and the next doesn't again, if these were actually on two different parallel workflows that would explain the situation. Branch 1 has commit 1 and 3, which has the files, branch 2 has commit 2 and 4 which doesn't, but you've interleaved them in the script.

Comment: Since you haven't told us how you generate the data, nor what you intend to use it for, it's quite difficult to give you any kind of answer.

Comment: If you reduce your problem to "there is a file which is reported for one commit but not for another", then it would be much easier to investigate.